# How to make a simple counter function in JavaScript that increments on a condition

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a simple javascript counter that should have a variable named "seq" set to 0 on page load, and increments every time a button is clicked. I've created a function of what I think it should look like, but am not sure if it is the right approach. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
var seqcounter = function () {
  seq = 0;
  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    seq++;
  });
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: What does the OP want to achieve with `seq`? Should this variable be kept entirely in a local scope? Is there a need of accessing the value of `seq` from outside? Should the incrementation of the counter value immediately update/refresh something else?

Comment: @duk3csmaj0r ... OP, please stay in the correct comment/thread ... *"would you say my approach is an okay way to go about it?"* ... *not yet* and *it depends*. And please answer the first two questions, not necessarily for *BenM* and me but mostly for yourself.

Comment: The question isn't really a valid question, insofar as it asks for a code review and doesn't describe a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mybe better to write this way :

```
var seq = 0;
var increaseSeq = function (){
seq++;
}

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click",
increaseSeq
//change with help of @peter seliger
);
```

Comment: What is the additional anonymous function expression wrapped around an `increaseSeq` call needed for? Also why does this approach drop the already more sophisticated approach of the OP ( which encloses the `seq`) in favor of a poor man's approach which increments a global variable?

Comment: @duk3csmaj0r ... The OP should really think twice about using the above code as solution, especially since the OP's code already has it all with the exception of not having everything assembled in the most logic/straightforward way.

Comment: Well, that depends on the level of the programmer and where he is using it.

Comment: your first comment is about this , right?:

`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", 
increaseSeq
);`

Comment: regarding your second comment ... yes.

Comment: @PeterSeliger would you say my approach is an okay way to go about it?